# How to simplify this R code(xmlToList)

Tags: r, xml

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
xmlfile=xmlParse("http://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/govdownload?dataid=F-D0047-089&authorizationkey=rdec-key-123-45678-011121314")
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root
T01 <- xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[3]][[5]])
T02 <- xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[4]][[5]])
T03 <- xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[5]][[5]])
T04 <- xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[6]][[5]])
T05 <- xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[7]][[5]])
T01 <-ldply(T01, data.frame)
T02 <-ldply(T02, data.frame)
T03 <-ldply(T03, data.frame)
T04 <-ldply(T04, data.frame)
T05 <-ldply(T05, data.frame)
taiwan_tt <- data.frame(T01,T02,T03,T04,T05)
```

How to simplify this code?
I try use this.

```
T01 <- xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[seq(3,7)]][[5]])
T01 <-ldply(T01, data.frame)
```

but it didn't work
please help me

Comment: You can remove those ugly newlines with `T01[] <- lapply(T01, function(x) sub("\n", "", x, fixed = TRUE))`. Then you will still have some clean up work to do.

Comment: i don't understand :((

Comment: For what I've seen, you have a messy data frame. It needs to be cleaned up. After `ldply` use the code line in my comment. It will remove the `'\n'` from your column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

See if this gets you any closer to what you need.

```
# This is your code, commented out
#library(XML)
#library(plyr)

#xmlfile=xmlParse("http://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/govdownload?dataid=F-D0047-089&authorizationkey=rdec-key-123-45678-011121314")
#xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root
```

Now for the simplification you've asked. At least, some of it.

```
T0_list <- lapply(3:7, function(i) xmlToList(xmltop[[9]][[i]][[5]]))
names(T0_list) <- paste0('T0', 1:5)
T0_list <- ldply(T0_list, data.frame)
T0_list <- lapply(T0_list, function(T0){
                T0 <- lapply(T0, function(x) sub("\n", "", x, fixed = TRUE))
                T0 <- as.data.frame(T0)
                T0
            })
```

The list `T0_list` now has the df's `T01` to `T05` of your post, with the newlines `'\n'` cleaned up.